# vite build does not produce javascript file in dist folder

Tags: javascript, firebase, vite

I am trying to deploy my vanilla JS app to Firebase hosting.
I am using Vite as a build tool.

When I run it locally, it works fine. But when I deploy it to Firebase hosting, I realized that it was missing `main.js` file.

I checked my `dist` folder generated by Vite, and it was indeed missing `main.js` file.

I never ran into this issue before when using JS framework, but now I am with Vanilla JS.

How can I make sure that my build will contain javascript file as well?

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction  of the problem?

Comment: @tony19 Hello Tony. Here is the link to my source code. I think this shouldnt be an issue when i use a framework but when using plan javascript this file always gets missing.. https://github.com/leochoo/emotion

Comment: @tony19 I asked a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69820257/javascript-file-missing-when-buildling

Answer (score 2):

Your script tag should look like this :

```
<script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
```

There must be an attribute :

```
type="module"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).