# JavaScript file missing when buildling

Tags: javascript, firebase, vite

I have a vanilla JS application. I'm using Vite as a frontend build tool.

```html
  <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
  <input type="button" value="Connect" onclick="connect();" />
```

The code above works locally, but when it builds, it does NOT produce JS file in the `dist` folder (which I set to deploy), and hence the program errors when deployed.

[image]

The error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: connect is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick`

How can I solve this?
I deployed it to Firebase hosting using Vite to build.

Edit:
I moved `main` branch to Svelte so it works, but vanilla js does not work, which is in the `petite-vue` branch. If you want to test it out for the error, please check out this branch.

The source code is here
https://github.com/leochoo/emotion/blob/petite-vue/index.html

Comment: I just cloned and after `yarn && yarn build` then deployed the app, the js `index` and `vendor` files are **ok** and the connect button is also **ok** asking for bluetooth access. You might try to delete the `node_modules` folder and regenerate your project deps.

Comment: @flydev Thanks for checking and sorry for the trouble. I moved the project from plain js to Svelte, made it a module and it works. I should have linked it to the commit where it was problematic. I will be posting a better question.. my bad.

Comment: @flydev I just edited the link. If you go to `petite-vue` branch, it will run fine locally when doing things like npm run start, but when you `npm run build`, it ignores main.js and just produces html file in the dist folder...  I did try to delete node_modules and reinstalled

Answer (score 0):

I think your project is a bit *messed*, I made you a working example `vite + svelte + microbit` available on Github :

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-microbit

Just clone the repo, then run `yarn` and `yarn build`

Comment: Wow. Thank you for taking your time for this. I will try it tomorrow!